# Events fact table: multiple rows per event

Tags: analytics, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I'm designing a events table that incorporates customer behavior in many different settings, application usage, support tickets, purchases, and etc.

But given the information in each type of event differ quite a bit, I'm considering using multiple DB rows per event, in order to accomodate arbitrary k/v in each event.

Is this a standard practice or anti-pattern? Is there a better approach?

Comment: Are you designing a transactional system (I.e. recording the events as they happen) or an analytical system (i.e. the data already exists in a source system and you want to query it effectively)?

Comment: @NickW analytical, stored as parquet and queried via spark sql. But now that you mention it, I'm curious about the OLTP side as well

Comment: In any single query, would you only want to include events of the same type or would you want to include events of all types? If queries are type-specific (and there is little commonality between types) then probably put each event type in its own table. If you want to query across all event types then have a single table - either containing all attributes or only common attributes and then with sub-tables for each event type

Comment: @NickW well, there are already six distinct event types, and likely increasing. Some queries do require multiple event types. but containing all attributes would result in a sparse table (would it also be hard to manage?). For sub-tables, is that a standard practice?

Comment: There are 3 options: 1 table for all events; 1 table per event type; 1 super table with sub-tables for each event type. There is no right answer, all are valid options. Which one is correct for you is dependant on how you want to query the data, ease of loading the tables v. ease of querying them, etc. Without someone knowing all the relevant information about your business, your data, etc they couldn’t answer this for you.